# If you didn’t put on tefilin at shacharis, when should you?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, tefilin, mincha-afternoon-prayer, zerizut-alacrity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Putting on tefillin late](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/323/putting-on-tefillin-late)

Someone was unable to put on tefilin when he 'davened' (prayed) shacharis.

When should he put on tefilin — immediately when he has the opportunity or when he davens mincha?

Comment: Zrizin makdimin

Comment: @ba What a good comment 1 minute after I posted the question!

Comment: How about both? Right now lest you forget, and during Mincha because it's better to daven with tefillin on, and now you have an excuse to during mincha (something the minhag is generally not to do otherwise).

Comment: @DoubleAA and Avrohom Yitzchok, please provide a source regarding an importance of wearing tefillin at mincha.

Comment: @YDK ShA OC 37:2

Comment: duplicate? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/323/759

Comment: Yes, wear them during Mincha and wear them all day :)

Comment: @DoubleAA Well spotted. Vote to close.

Comment: Ok then, closing.

Answer (score 3):

BS"D

Immediately.

**"When does the time to put them [Tephilin] on begin? When one can see a colleague standing four cubits away and recognize him, until sunset."** *[M"T Hilkhoth Tephilin u'Mezuzah w'Seipher Torah 4:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2304n.htm#10)*

**"The holiness associated with tefillin is very great. As long as a person is wearing tefillin on his head and arm, he will be humble and God-fearing and will not be drawn to frivolous behavior or empty speech. He will not turn his thoughts to evil matters, but rather will direct his heart to words of truth and justice.
Accordingly, a person should try to wear [tefillin] throughout the entire day, for this is the mitzvah associated with them. Among the praises conveyed upon Rav, the student of Rabbenu Hakadosh, was that he was never seen walking four cubits without [reciting words of] Torah, without tzitzit, and without tefillin."** *[M"T Hilkhoth Tephilin u'Mezuzah w'Seipher Torah 4:25](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2304n.htm#25)*

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @YDK Why not? Avrohom Yitzchok asked if one should wait till minhhah to put on tephilin or to do it immediately. From the sources I posted and the entirety of chapter 4 its clear , at least to me, that one should strive to wear them throughout all the day hours. Thus eliminating any reason ( based off of the scenario given) putting off wearing them.

Comment: @YDK, this was the pesak I received when I asked this question l'maaseh.

Comment: @Qoheleth, but perhaps for the same reason most do not accustom themselves accordingly and only wear them during the time of tefilla when we are focused, one who missed the time should also postpone putting them on until a time of tefilla.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu, I'm not contradicting the pesak, I just don't think the above sources speak to that point.

Comment: Qoheleth, I understand that back in the day (and probably even now for some people) tefillin were worn all day; however, I think the question was asking according to the minhag which is popular nowadays among most Jews that tefillin are only worn during Shacharit. So I agree with @YDK that this doesn't answer the intended question, although perhaps the OP's meaning was unclear.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah I wasn't trying to push my understanding of the Halakha of tephilin against peoples minhagim but I still believe its inline with the OP's question "immediately he has the opportunity or when he davens mincha?" , from this it seems, to me, hes already talking about out side just the confines of times of prayers. Hes asking whether he should right away (after tephila) or wait till he prays again. Should have the OP clarify.

Comment: @Qoheleth He has prayed shacharis. It will be at least 3 hours before he can pray mincha. Should he put on tefillin now or wait and put them on at mincha??

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok my community holds by the Halakha that if you don't have a reason not to be wearing tephilin then you should be. But Like DoubleAA pointed out many peoples minhagim is in contradiction to the Halakha I posted. So contact the Orthodox Rabbi whom you hold by, If you want to know more about the Halakha's about wearing Tephilin you can read about them here : http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925425/jewish/Chapter-Four.htm