# Which communities wear tefilin while davening Minha?

Tags: tefilin, mincha-afternoon-prayer, communities

Which communities wear tefilin while davening Minha on ordinary weekdays? I was told by my Rav that some do.

Comment: I once heard that some Sepharadim do.

Comment: Thanks. Which ones ?

Comment: I'm unsure. I heard it from a piece written by R' Hamburger which was bringing a source for 9 Av at minchah.

Comment: @maaaan. The following link explains that there are several types of tefilin containing different passages (or order of passages.) Rashi version has become standard. Kabbalistic believe that one should daven Shacharit in Rashi and Shimusha Raba during mincha. So perhaps the answer is, Kabbalistic (or those who tend to that belief) wear tefillin twice. The link also gives other possibilities including the fact that we are suppose to wear tefillin all day and that if it was an isolated incident, the person may have not yet have said Shacharit.   http://ohr.edu/3943

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer! Do you understand this part of the link : "Since tefillin worn backward does not disqualify the mitzvah (O.Ch.,M.B. 27:12), wearing Rashi or R.T. is like reversing Shimusha Raba or Ra’avad tefillin respectively. In this way, each pair of either Rashi or R.T. worn the right way simultaneously fulfills the corresponding opinion in the de facto, reversed way. Thus, all four opinions can be fulfilled with only two pair." If wearing tefilin backward does not fulfill the mitswa, how can the 4 opinions be fulfilled with only two pairs?

Comment: @maaaan. I am a bit lost myself! This is how I understand it. If the sequence of passages in front and left to right is 1, 2, 3 and 4, the back would be 4, 3, 2 and 1. If wearing tefillin backwards still fulfills the mitzvah, then you can argue and say you have fulfilled 1, 2, 3, and 4 as well as 4, 3, 2, and 1. The second pair of tefillin would fulfill the other two opinions since 1, 2, 4, 3 reversed would be 3, 4, 2 , 1. So it appears that two sets of tefillin fulfills four opinions. Not to make this more complicated maaaan, but I wonder if everyone agrees wearing tefillin backwards is okay.

Answer (score 3):

Technically the Zilberman community in the old city do, but they wear them all day anyway

Answer (score 2):

The [Teshuvos VeHanhagos](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20025&st=&pgnum=46) mentions a few:

1. Some communities in Israel (now and during the time of the Reishis Chochma)
2. R' Velvel Brisker
3. The Rama MiPano

Comment: 2 & 3 are not communities. 1 needs a source. +1 anyway.

Comment: @mevaqesh better?

Comment: It could be further improved with the identities of the these communities and some reference to their practice. Even if the source is personal observation, noting this would improve the question. Regarding the Reishis Chochmah, is this something that he writes? If so, where?

Answer (score 1):

> Regarding your seeing people wearing tefillin during mincha, there are several possible explanations:
>
> 1] They may have missed shacharit or wearing Rashi tefillin for whatever reason, so they endeavor to fulfill that day’s mitzvah of tefillin at least during the mincha prayer rather than at some other time of the day.
>
> 2] Since technically speaking the mitzvah of tefillin is to wear them all day long, even though this is not done, some choose to wear Rashi tefillin at least during mincha in addition to shacharit.
>
> 3] According to the kabbalists, in addition to using Rashi and Rabbeinu Tam tefillin in shacharit, one should use Shimusha Raba tefillin in mincha.

Source: ohr.edu/3943

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I agree that only the 3) answer the question. But the 1° and 2° also help understand why some people where tefilin while davening mincha.

Comment: How does 3 answer anything? Is there a community that follows this position? I can find lots of sources that suggest one should. The question was which communities __do__ do it

Comment: If they should do it, there is a good chance some do do it. And "doing it" is not only about the "facts" it is also regarding the law: Kabbalist do wear the tefilin while davening mincha, at least according to Kabbala...

Comment: Ok but who are they? The Shulchan Arukh also recommends wearing Tefillin during Mincha. But who follows that?

Comment: That I don't know. For now we only know it is "the kabbalists". Also, what is the source for the Shulchan Aruch please.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18780/if-you-didn-t-put-on-tefilin-at-shacharis-when-should-you?rq=1#comment45971_18780