# Should one wear tefillin for tashlumin for Shacharis?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tefilin, mincha-afternoon-prayer, tashlumin

Let's say Aharon missed Shacharis. He needs to pray Shemoneh Esrei twice by mincha time to make it up, which is called "*tashlumin*" (תשלומין). ([OC 108:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x473))

Now, Aharon can put on tefilin at any point in the day (though he won't do so [at night](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x384)).

Is there any reason to put them on specifically when he davens (prays) his *tashlumin* ([the second prayer](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x473))? After all, that prayer is a stand-in for Shacharis.

*I'm looking for an answer that says "this sefer says" or the equivalent; I'm also capable of saying "hey, can't hurt, right?"*

Comment: Clearly not [Rfפ](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3406), because [the OP's name](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52899/choosing-between-brachos-on-shma-and-sof-zman-kriyas-shema#comment139679_52899) is not Aharon.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/323/759

Comment: Are you asking about Tashlumin to the exclusion of Mincha or if he should leave them on after Mincha for Tashlumin as well?

Comment: Re your final clause, would this suffice as an answer http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18780/if-you-didn-t-put-on-tefilin-at-shacharis-when-should-you?lq=1#comment45983_18780 ? IMO it says more than "hey, can't hurt, right?"; it says "hey it's a chance to accomplish two important Mitzvot Deorayta." (Please be sure to look up the referenced source and not just take it in the context of the comments there.)

Comment: @DoubleAA First: I'm not sure what's unclear about the question. Second: No. Most of us don't do that anymore, anyway. Is there a specific reason to put on tefillin for the makeup shemoneh esrei?

Comment: Can you indicate why there would be a connection between Shacharit prayers _qua_ Shacharit and Tefillin? I know of none. (Don't say "I see lots of people wear it then". That doesn't prove they are doing so because of Shacharit _per se_.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Regarding your last point: I don't know of one either; I'm pretty sure that's part of the question.

Comment: Nobody seems to talk about it. Though the Kitzur Yalkut Yosef says about Tashlumim for Maariv:  והדבר פשוט שאין צריך להסיר את התפילין בעת שמתפלל תפלה שניה לתשלומי ערבית, אף שאין להניח תפילין בתפלת ערבית. http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_6.html#HtmpReportNum0027_L2

Answer (score 2):

[Rabbi Rachamum Mazuz quoting Yalkut Yosef 1:78](http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/5715&pgnm=1) in a case where one missed Shacharus and Musaf on Rosh Chodesh says that first he should put on Tefilin and remove them, then Daven Mincha, then Daven Musaf, and then do Tashlumim for Shacharis.

> קודם כל יניח תפלין בברכה ויוריד אותו, ואח"כ יתפלל מנחה, ואחריה תפלת
>   מוסף, ואח"כ תשלומין של שחרית

The way I understand this ruling: If there was a reason to specifically put them on for the Shacharis Tashlumin, why not answer first Daven Mincha, then Daven Musaf, then put on Tefilin and Daven the Shacharis Tashlumin? However he does not say so, leading me to believe it is not necessary nor is there any reason to do so.

However [Birur Halacha 108](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50533&st=&pgnum=35&hilite=) quoting Rabbi Moshe Nechemia Kahanow Z"L says that one should put on Tefilin when he is Davening Mincha, and keep it on for the Tashlumim if he has not put it on yet that day.