# Wearing tallit "late"

Tags: tefilin, zemanim, tallit-gadol

Based on [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/323/putting-on-tefillin-late) question.

If one (who has the tradition of wearing a tallit while davening shacharit, be it because he is married, or over 13) can not wear a tallit in the morning, does he put one on later in the day (while it is still day) to fulfill some independent obligation?

Is the [wearing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81409/why-do-we-don-a-tallit-before-laying-tefillin) of a [tallit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66087/why-do-we-don-the-tallit-gadol) for a "regular person" (not the shaliach tzibbur) tied to saying shacharit, or tied to putting tefillin on? If I don't have my tefillin at shacharit, but have my tallit, do I wear the tallit (on Shabbat I wear a tallit and no tefillin) and if I put my tefillin on later in the day (as per the related question) do I put the tallit on also? If I have my tefillin, but no tallit, do I forego the tefillin at shacharit and wait until I have both?

And, of course, is any of this changed by my wearing a tallit kattan?

Answer (score 1):

As codified in Shulchan Aruch (OC [19:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%98)) the requirement to don *tzitzit* is an obligation on the individual, i.e. when one wears a garment which meets the requirements of the laws of *tzitzit* he is then obligated to attach the strings. One is not obligated to purchase a kosher garment bearing *tzitzit* in order to fulfill the commandment (cf. Beer Heitiv [OC 17:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x371)), however it is preferable to do so as it is of great significance (see SA [ibid. 24:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%90); the rabbis have much discussion about the notion of proactively obligating oneself in *mitzvot* generally but that is off topic). This is the only biblical "obligation". Therefore, if one does not have a *talit* *gadol* or *tzitzit* while praying, and he prays without them, he may don them later in the day but is not *halachically* obligated to do so.

*Tzitzit* is tied to praying in certain areas of prayer and SA (ibid) therefore recommends the donning of *tzitzit* at least during prayers.

Since the donning of *tzitzit* and *tefilin* are not halachically bound together, if one has *tzitzit* by prayers but does not have *tefilin* they may pray with *tzitzit* alone. When they don the *tefilin* later (in order not to transgress the rabbinic dicutm (Ber. [14b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%91)) "one who reads the *keriat shema* without wearing *tefilin* is likened to offering false testimony") there is no halachic obligation to re-don the *tzitzit*. If the case is the opposite, one dons the *tefilin* without the *tzitzit* since, again, the two are not mutually conditional.

If one was wearing a *talit katan* all along, he has fulfilled the *tzitzit* commandment (cf. SA ibid [8:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%97_%D7%92)) and is not at all obligated to don the *talit gadol* later in the event that he did not have it while praying or wearing *tefilin* and would like to don them together.